# Nexus Sonartype | Startup issue | Codehaus Snapshots Issue

Tags: repository, nexus

*Hello Good People* - Need your expertise/pointers:

### Getting the below error while starting up Nexus application repo.

**Message in the wrapper.log**:

*jvm 1    | 2019-07-24 15:13:24 INFO  [ehaus-snapshots] - org.sonatype.nexus.proxy.registry.DefaultRepositoryRegistry-codehaus-snapshots - Next attempt to auto-unblock the "**Codehaus Snapshots**" (id=codehaus-snapshots) repository by checking its remote peer health will occur in 3 minutes 20 seconds*.

Not able to start nexus instance

```
Error:
jvm 1    | 2019-07-24 15:30:45 INFO  [qtp398357230-60] - org.sonatype.security.model.source.FileModelConfigurationSource - Loading Security configuration from /opt/nexus/nexus-2.0.6/./../sonatype-work/nexus/conf/security.xml
jvm 1    | 2019-07-24 15:30:45.505:INFO:/nexus:nexus: [Noelios Restlet Engine] - Attaching application: org.sonatype.nexus.rest.NexusApplication@554795bd to URI: /nexus
jvm 1    | 2019-07-24 15:44:44 INFO  [ehaus-snapshots] - org.sonatype.nexus.proxy.registry.DefaultRepositoryRegistry-codehaus-snapshots - Next attempt to auto-unblock the "Codehaus Snapshots" (id=codehaus-snapshots) repository by checking its remote peer health will occur in 22 minutes 40 seconds.
```

#### Nexus instance is not starting and getting "site not reachable" error in a browser

Comment: The log you posted actually indicates that NXRM is up and running, but it will not send any outbound requests to codehaus-snapshots repository, because it is has been automatically blocked. This is done when a proxy repository is not responding or is returning errors and you can change the setting in your proxy repository configuration.

Comment: And it is expected for codehaus not to work, that site went off the internet years ago:  https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/217611787-codehaus-org-Repositories-Should-Be-Removed-From-Your-Nexus-Instance